# Cannot render 16:9 video for youtube

Tags: vegas-pro, youtube

I downloaded [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tae1GuzUccY) YT video, and want to make it 16:9 in Vegas 10 pro.

Here is my file settings:

Template - HD 1080 24p (1920x1080, 29.970 fps)
Frame rate - 29.970(NTSC)
Field order - None (progressive scan)

Render settings:
Save as type - Sony AVC (*.mp4,*.m2ts,*.avc)
Template - Internet1280x720-30p
Bit rate - 8,000,000

Right click on video track - properties - Maintain aspect ratio is not checked.

Playing in Vegas is fine, but rendered video is full of interruptions, freeze places...
Audio sounds ok.
Rendering still images with the above settings is ok.

Any help, pls.

Comment: Is the problem that the video does not render at 16:9, or is it that the rendered video stutters and freezes?

Comment: @Tortilla, the starting video is not 16:9, and my resulting video is 16:9, but video stutters and freezes. I didn't make any other changes in Vegas except changing aspect ratio. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to disable graphic card rendering? Incompatible graphic cards or drivers may cause the exact symptoms you describe. Preview may not use graphic card rendering, as this is controlled by another setting.

- Select Options|Preferences
- Go to tab card "Video"
- Set "GPU acceleration of video processing" to "Off"
- When rendering: Open your render template and select Encode Mode:
  Render using CPU only.

Comment: No need to apologize for not being able to comment.  This is fine as a possible solution for the problem and provides the detail for how to attempt to fix it, so it really is an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The source video from YouTube is Standard Definition not HD, so your project properties in Vegas are not set right nor can they be set to 1080p. Simply, you can't take an SD video and make it into an HD video.

The proper way to set Vegas project properties is to use the folder icon far right top of the properties pop up window, this will allow you to "match media settings" so that your Vegas project has correctly identified your source material.

Here is a short YouTube Tutorial on this:

No matter, you still won't be able to take SD video and make it HD, but at least your project will start out on the right foot.